# How can one calculate (x,y) co-ordinates if margin between two lines(outer and inner) are given in terms of pixels?

Tags: c++, c++11, coordinate

I need to draw double frame on a display device to display a frame.
I have the (x,y) co-ordinates of outer frame and I have the margin between the outer and inner frames in terms of pixels.

Please suggest a formula to calculate (x,y) coordinates of the inner frame?

Comment: Homework? What have you tried so far? Show us your attempt and say what's wrong with it.

Comment: This question is not strictly related to programming. Maybe it's best suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Neb The question is slightly unclear (e.g. how many xy pairs), but even otherwise I think it would be laughed at by the math gurus.

Comment: @Yunnosch I suppose there are 4 points for the outer frame and 4 for the inner one but the OP should confirm. Anyway, this is not a programming problem

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], a program defining the environment of your question. How is the input data represented? Where does the result need to go? What is the definition of input and output?

Comment: @Neb For a programming beginner, this might be a programming problem, even if not for a programming guru. Keep in mind that programming also involves designing a solution, which involves abstracting or representing the non-programming aspects of the goal and that these things tend to be an obstacle for new programmers.

Comment: As a side note: In case of something like a window/dialog, maybe the frame you should draw is the outer frame, not the inner frame, becaue drawing inside of the frame window might hide part of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Take pen & paper.
Draw the outer frame.
Mark the points defined by your xy pairs.
Draw the inner frame.
What are the differences (expressed in x and y) between the spots marked on the outer frame and the corresponding spots on the inner frame?

If you can express that in some kind of formula, you are already close to the code. You just need to turn your formulas into assignment statements.

Without an MCVE to define the environment of your question, giving a solution in code is not possible. However, in case of a homework assignment (skyjacks impression seems plausible), I anyway follow the policy not to provide final solutions and instead give hints to help on the right track.
Which I just did. ;-)

*(If this is no homework, then you have of course already a program as context and will not have a problem making an MCVE. In that case I will be happy to help with this programming detail.)*